# STM32F4 Hanging in I2C_CheckEvent()

Tags: c, i2c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I've been finding that the I2C communication between my STM32F4 and IMU device randomly hangs. The STM32F4 is the master and the only other device on the bus is an IMU6050 6 axis accel/gyro. The program ends up hanging by getting stuck in a loop within the I2C_CheckEvent() function.

Initialization is as follows:

```
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;            
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;       
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;          
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;            
GPIO_Init(DATAPORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);                   
GPIO_PinAFConfig(DATAPORT, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(DATAPORT, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_I2C1);

/* Set the I2C parameters, pretty much default except ack */
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStructure);

/* Enable the I2C peripheral */
I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

/* Config the IMU with defult settings */
IMUConfig(DEFAULTACCELRANGE, DEFAULTGYRORANGE);
```

The initialization of the IMU is taken care of, I'm sure that all works as I get valid data for a little while. The application randomly crashes after a few seconds of running.

The read function:

```
void IMUReadBytes(uint8_t startAddress, uint8_t numOfBytes, uint8_t *location){
    I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));

    I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, IMU_ADDRESS << 1, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED));

    I2C_SendData(I2C1, startAddress);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED));

    I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));

    I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, IMU_ADDRESS << 1, I2C_Direction_Receiver);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_RECEIVER_MODE_SELECTED));

    int num = 0;
    for(num = 0; num <= numOfBytes; num++){
        if(num == numOfBytes){
            I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C1, DISABLE);
            I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2C1, ENABLE);
        }

        while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_RECEIVED));
        location[num] = I2C_ReceiveData(I2C1);
    }
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C1, ENABLE);
}
```

Each time, the application seems to crash via one of the while check events, it's different each time.

Possibly unrelated, but when compiling, I get the warning:

```
source\application\source\imu.c:129:5: warning: passing argument 3 of 'IMUReadBytes' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
source\application\source\imu.c:81:6: note: expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t (*)[14]'
```

I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

As I said, the code works fine for a little while, sometime even a couple mins. I've got the gyro and accel values linked to some motors and during the time it works, everything runs perfectly. No idea why it gets stuck

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include how do you call `IMUReadBytes(...)` and you have a compiler warning related to this. Also without real code it can not be seen whether you run out of range for `location` or not.

However to narrow the problem down I would recommend to split the whole code to parts, and first run something kind of:

```
while(1)
 {
  while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_RECEIVED));
  unsigned char readbyte = I2C_ReceiveData(I2C1);
  printf("%x ",readbyte);
 }
```

The point here is to have a simple robust loop which always reads the data and outputs it to you. So you would be able to run this an see whether the hanging happens or not. Such a loop doesn't affect other memory which potentially excludes some issues with data corruption and others, more or less not related to I2C things.

Do you have a serial port in there that you could print out from your system? It's the biggest helper in debugging.

Another approach is triggering the bus data on oscilloscope if you have one.

Otherwise you will need analyze your program only by watching in code and docs.